# Error 404 issue

Tags: http-status-code-404

My site is redirecting the wrong or non existent pages to index.php but i want it to redirect to my custom Error 404 page,
I tried with htaccess command also - ErrorDocument 404 /404-error-page.html , but still no use .My server is host gator.Can anyone help with this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a great video tutorial =) http://www.hostgator.com/tutorials/xskincpanel/cpanel_xskin_errorpages.htm

and if you preffer to read http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/custom-error-pages

I don't worki in hostgator :P but if this didn't help I can try to help you find the why anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

Then you probably have this in your htaccess : ErrorDocument 404 /index.html

To redirect errors to a custom page add this to your .htaccess in your public folder

```
ErrorDocument 403 /403.shtml
ErrorDocument 404 /404.shtml
ErrorDocument 500 /500.shtml
```

more info [here](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/custom-error-pages)